# moodle browse user's list

Tags: php, ajax, moodle

how to change the search style on moodle?

[image]

I want to change it as live search. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. You should have a hands on experience with PHP and Javascript/AJAX. 
The native search feature of moodle will not be in use any more. You can just hide that by css and inroduce your search field in the search_form.php
 After that you can either write the search code by yourself or use some frameworks like [this](https://searchwp.com/extensions/live-search/).